# What is the difference between printf to return?

Tags: c

Compute the sum of the two given integer values. If the two values are the same, then return triple their sum.

```
int main() {
    printf("%d\n", test(1, 2));
    printf("%d", test(2, 2));
}

int test(int x, int y) {
    int sum;

    if (x == y) {
        sum = (x + y) * 3;
        printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
    } else  {
        sum = (x + y);
        printf("sum = %d", sum);
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get the wrong output, but when I use `return` statements instead of the `printf`, I get the right input.  Why?

Comment: Using a function to calculate a value, and using a function to put that value on the screen, are two different things.  You might want to put the value in a file, or a database, or send it over a network, or a million other things with it.  Not everything you do should be printed out.

Comment: @nanofarad `printf` writes to stdout.  Often, stdout is associated with a terminal, which is often misnamed a "console". But you ought not conflate the two.

Comment: Since `test` does not return a value (there is no `return` statement), the attempt to reference the return value results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As a general rule you should enable all warnings in your compiler and read them carefully. You should get some warning about reaching end of non-void function without returning a value. For GCC you can use `-Wall -Wextra` to increase warning leve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is just a little bit wrong. Keeping with the general structure of your code, here are two ways that you can rewrite it.

#1: Instead of returning a value, the `test` function prints a value. Since `test` does not return a value, you must put the keyword `void` before the function name.  To get the values to print, the `main` function must call the `test` function.

```
int main() {

    /** calls the test function,
        then the test function prints
        the sum value **/
    test(1,2); 
    test(2,2);

    return 0;
}

void test(int x, int y) {

    int sum;

    if (x == y) {
        sum = (x + y) * 3;
        printf("sum = %d\n", sum); /** prints the sum value**/
    } else  {
        sum = (x + y);
        printf("sum = %d", sum); /** prints the sum value**/
    }
}
```

#2 The `test` function returns the `sum` value. Since `sum` is an `int`, you must put the keyword `int` before the function name. The `main` function gets the value of `sum` by calling the `test` function. Then `main` prints this value.

```
int main() {

    /** prints the value returned 
        by the test function **/
    printf("%d\n", test(1,2)); 
    printf("%d", test(2,2));

    return 0;
}

int test(int x, int y) {

    int sum;

    if (x == y) {
        sum = (x + y) * 3;
    } else  {
        sum = (x + y);    
    }

    /** returns the value of sum **/
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since `test` does not return a value (there is no `return` statement), the attempt to reference the return value results in undefined behavior.  It might be easier to understand what is happening in your program if you make a few minor modifications:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
test(int x, int y)
{
        int sum = x + y;
        if( x==y ){
                sum *= 3;
        }
        printf("sum = %d XXX ", sum);
        return sum;
}

int
main(void)
{
        printf("** %d **\n", test(1, 2));
        printf("** %d **\n", test(2, 2));
        return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program is:

```
sum = 3 XXX ** 3 **
sum = 12 XXX ** 12 **
```

The `test` in the argument list to `printf` in `main` is called before the `printf` in `main` can be called.  The `printf` inside the `test` function executes and prints `sum = ... XXX` .  The function returns a value which is passed as an argument to the `printf` in main which prints `** ... **`.